# Returns data as Null after calling the subscribe method of httpget from component

Tags: angular, service

Here is my component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CclcService } from '../cclc.service';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaderResponse,HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { ICurrencyData } from './ICurrencyData';
import { Currency } from './Currency';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cryto-currencies-list',
  templateUrl: './cryto-currencies-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cryto-currencies-list.component.css']
})
export class CrytoCurrenciesListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private cclcService: CclcService ) {
      console.log('cclc component called');
   }

   public list : Currency;

   ngOnInit() {    
      this.getCurrencyList();
   }

   public getCurrencyList() 
   {
       this.cclcService.getCryptoCurrencyList().subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.list = data;
         console.log(this.list );
       })
   }
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaderResponse,HttpClientModule,HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ICurrencyData } from './cryto-currencies-list/ICurrencyData';
import { Currency } from './cryto-currencies-list/Currency';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

})

export class CclcService {
  private list : ICurrencyData[];

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient ,private data:ICurrencyData,private resp: HttpHeaderResponse,private route:Router,actRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log('cclc service constructor called');
    resp.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   }
   private baseUrl = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/';
   private apiKey= 'bf8bbb9e-a227-46cb-862d-53a9ad3bbe51';

   public getCryptoCurrencyList() : Observable<Currency>
   {
     return this.httpClient.get<Currency>(this.baseUrl + 
      'v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=' + this.apiKey)
      console.log('service');          
   }
}
```

I am calling a web api get operation through a service using http client module. But the data returns as null after the subscribe method is called from component. It worked perfectly fine when the request is called through post man.

Ideally It should return a json result.

But getting the data as null when the subscribe request is completed successfully

```
cclc service constructor called
cryto-currencies-list.component.ts:18 cclc component called
cclc.service.ts:30 service
cclc.service.ts:31 Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
cryto-currencies-list.component.ts:28 null
cryto-currencies-list.component.ts:30 null
```

Comment: Have you checked your currency model matches the response body of the API call?  When your app calls the API, have you checked what is returned in the developer console in Chrome?

Comment: Yes the model matches the response data format and in the developer console It is showing the response data as null

Comment: I believe Mark means the actual response you get that you can see in the network tab if the data structure matches the model

Comment: Try hitting the same get API directly in browser address bar and see if you get result.

Comment: Thanks. It is showing the proper result by hitting the same get API directly in browser address bar and In the console Network tab of chrome It does not show any response. Any way It is working in firefox and not in Chrome/IE/Edge even by adding CORS Extension